# SQL query using GROUP_CONCAT() function

Tags: sql, sqlite, rdbms

I have two tables:

```
1.Activity-- which stores all the activities from a user
2.User-- which stores all the registered users
```

I want to fetch all the posts and the likes to all posts in one query. A row is a post or like is decided by the value of **type** column.

**Table Name - Activity**

```
|  actId  |  parentId  |  type     |  postedby    |
---------------------------------------------------
|  100    |  NULL      |  post     | 100          |
|  200    |  100       |  like     | 200          |
|  300    |  100       |  like     | 300          |
|  400    |  100       |  like     | 400          |
|  500    |  NULL      |  post     | 100          |
|  600    |  500       |  like     | 600          |
```

**Table Name - User**

```
|  userId  |  name    |
-------------------
|  100     |  Amit    |
|  200     |  Alok    |
|  300     |  Arjun   |
|  400     |  Arpeet  |
|  600     |  Amaan   |
```

The output should be

```
|  actId  |  name  |  LikedBy            |
------------------------------------------
|  100    |  Amit  |  Alok, Arjun, Arpeet|
|  500    |  Amit  |  Amaan              |
```

**NOTE** - I don't want this to be achieved using **FOR XML PATH** since it is not supported in SQLite which I am working on.

My query attempt was

```
SELECT  a.id, u.name,
(select group_concat(u.name) from activity a, user u where a.id = u.id and a.type = 'like'
group by a.parent) as likedby
FROM activity a, user u
WHERE a.id = u.id  and a.type = 'post'
```

The result I got was

```
|  Id  |  name  |  LikedBy            |
---------------------------------------
|  100 |  Amit  |  Alok, Arjun, Arpeet|
```

You can see that the other row was missing from result.

Comment: For which DBMS do you need a solution?

Comment: @Jens, I need it for SQLite. But it might not mater a lot as the query will be almost same.

Comment: this is not true, GROUP_CONCAT() is a mysql related function, in SQL Server it is a recursive CTE (for example).

Comment: @ChandraSekhar So correct your tags.You should not tag your question with irrelevant DBMS systems

Comment: What specific problem do you have with the group_concat() function? Show your query!

Comment: You can try COALESCE for the same.

Comment: @PareshJ, Since COALESCE is for returning the first non null value. How it will help achieving my problem?

Comment: @ChandraSekhar: I don't find id with 500 in `Name` table. So is it typo ?? and what is the purpose of `by` column in `Test` table ?

Comment: You should describe the your data and intended output. Otherwise we will be guessing.

Comment: @KrishnrajRana, by is meant for by whom that record is got created.

Comment: @CFreitas, Can you please see the updated question?

Comment: Please don't get me wrong, but I would rather have a description in English. Seeing the tables and a faulty SQL query ((because it does not output what you want)) is not enough for me to understand exactly what you want.

Comment: @CFreitas, Hope you can understand my requirement now. I have explained it in a better way. Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select t.id4id Id, n1.Name Name, group_concat(n2.name) Groups
from (select t1.actid id4id, t1.postedby id4name, t2.postedby id4groups
        from Activity t1 join Activity t2 on t1.actid = t2.parentid) t join "user" n1 on t.id4name = n1.userid join "User" n2 on t.id4groups = n2.userid
group by id4id
```

Notes: 1. I assume that a post will always have a null value in parent

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. It seems tough to understand. But still I will use it since its working fine for me as per my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a subquery for this.  You simply need two joins in order to get the values for the original name and the liked name:

```
select a.parentid, u.name, group_concat(ul.name separator ', ') as likedby
from activity a join
     user ul
     on a.postedby = ul.userid join
     user u
     on a.parentid = u.userid
where a.type = 'like'
group by a.parentid, u.name;
```